# Pascal типизированные файлы

Tags: файлы, pascal

Как можно просмотреть содержимое типизированного файла(внес ли я какую то информацию или нет), я создаю record и вношу к примеру в файл ABITUR.dat , и как понять внеслось ли там все корректно ? 
Вот код

```
Program DataOfStudents;
type
    F_I_O = record
        familia : String[25];
        imia : String[15];
        otchestvo : String[30];
    end;
    Ocenka = record
        predmet : String;
        ocenka : Byte;
    end;
    Abiturient = record
        fio : F_I_O;
        god_rozhd : Word;
        god_shkl : Word;
        attestat : 1..12;
        obsch : Boolean;
        ekzam : Array[0..2] Of Ocenka;
    end;

var
    a : Abiturient;
    i, j, n: Byte;
    s : String[3];
    f : File Of Abiturient;

begin
    Assign(f, 'd:\ABITUR.dat'); ReWrite(f);
    Write('Count of students: '); ReadLn(n);
    for i := 0 to n-1 do
    begin
        with a do
        begin
            with fio do
            begin
                Write('Second Name: '); ReadLn(familia);
                Write('First Name: '); ReadLn(imia);
                Write('Patronimyc: '); ReadLn(otchestvo);
            end;
            Write('Year of birth: '); ReadLn(god_rozhd);
            Write('Year (school finished): '); ReadLn(god_shkl);
            Write('Avarage rate of certificate: '); ReadLn(attestat);
            Write('Hostel [Yes / No]: '); ReadLn(s);
            obsch := (s = 'Yes');
            for j := 0 to 2 do
                with ekzam[j] do
                begin
                    Write('Name of exam: '); ReadLn(predmet);
                    Write('Rate: '); ReadLn(ocenka);
                end;
        end;
        Write(f, a);
    end;
    Close(f);
end.
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что может внестись некорректно?

Comment: Ну , хотелось бы наглядно продемонстрировать работу программы. Плюс мало понимающему человеку , сложно доказать к примеру что программа работает и как она работает.

Answer (score 1):

Ну или делать программу-читалку для вашего типизированного файла или чем-либо смотреть двоичные данные и пальцем считать байты. Я обычно смотрю far manager: кнопки: F3, F4

Comment: Скачал , попробовал через него открыть файл.
Пишет FILE d:\ABITUR.dat had too long lines first such lines is 2 
FILE d:\ABITUR.dat had too long lines first such lines is -1
И в итоге выводит какие то иероглифы .

Comment: сначала F3, потом F4, чтобы в Hex режим перейти

Comment: Не знаю норма ли это, но я пришел если там можно выразиться к цифровому виду. Куча различных цифр, и совсем справа от них , периодически встречаются слова которые я вводил в этот файл, но просмотр , данных если это так назвать все равно затруднен.

Comment: :) да таковы двоичные данные, если не нравится пишите читалку, 
где все будет наоборот, read<->write

Comment: Выходит без собственной читалки проверить корректность ввода данных в текстовом виде не представляется возможным ?

Comment: Конечно, вы ведь по сути создаёте собственный формат файла